# How to use detailview pk in createview

Tags: django

```py
# models.py

class NewBlank(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    blank_on_off = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class BlankContent(models.Model):
    refer = models.TextField()
    memo = models.TextField()
    new_blank = models.ForeignKey('NewBlank', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blankcontent')
```

```py
# views.py

class BlankDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = NewBlank
    template_name = 'blank_app/blank_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'blank'

class BlankContentCreate(CreateView):
    model = BlankContent
    fields = "__all__"
    template_name = 'blank_app/new_blank_content_create.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('blank_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.new_blank.pk})
```

```py
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('blank/<int:pk>/', BlankDetail.as_view(), name='blank_detail'),
    path('new-blank-content/', BlankContentCreate.as_view(), name='blank_content_create'),
]
```

There is a creativeview in the detail view and I want to create a model in the detailview when I press it. So even if I don't specify the new_blank part, I want it to be filled automatically according to the pk in the detailview, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to perform some extra work in your `DetailView`, one of the ways to do that would be to override the `get_object` method.

```py
from django.views.generic import DetailView


class BlankDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = NewBlank
    template_name = 'blank_app/blank_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'blank'

    def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object()
        # do your thing with obj.pk
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk') # in case you want to access the `pk` from URL
```